# How can I prevent the automatic visualization of large graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, output-formatting

Mathematica will always attempt to render graphs, no matter how large they are.  This is often very inconvenient because visualization can be slow, and a large graph that is present in a notebook even slows down scrolling.

How can I set thresholds for the `EdgeCount` and `VertexCount` so that visualization will not happen above these thresholds?  I would like to show these large graphs as if `GraphLayout -> None` were set:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, this works, but I am not fully confident that it will not break in any case.  One reason is that I am not sure what `GraphLayout` syntaxes are valid.  Note that pattern I used to test if the graph would be drawn.  Another reason is that I am not confident that the `SetProperty` call will not fail on any graph.

```
edgeThreshold = 10000;
vertexThreshold = 10000;
layoutQ[g_] := Not@MatchQ[Options[g, GraphLayout], {GraphLayout -> (None | {None, ___})}]
test[g_] :=
 GraphQ[g] &&
 layoutQ[g] &&
 (EdgeCount[g] > edgeThreshold || VertexCount[g] > vertexThreshold)

MakeBoxes[g_?test, form : StandardForm | TraditionalForm] := 
 With[{new = SetProperty[g, GraphLayout -> None]}, MakeBoxes[new, form]]
```

To be able to visualize a large graph when we need it, we can use

```
ShowGraph[g_?GraphQ] := 
    Block[{test = False &}, 
      Show@If[layoutQ[g], g, SetProperty[g, GraphLayout -> Automatic]]
    ]
```

This returns `Graphics`, not `Graph`.

Comment: Just to add a little context for googlers: the magic here is in the `MakeBoxes` function which is not fully protected (so you are allowed to write your own definitions for it). It gets called to prepare something to be displayed in the notebook. The reason for the `With[...` instead of just calling `MakeBoxes[SetProperty[...` is that MakeBoxes fully holds its arguments and you don't want to display the `SetProperty[...` expression. You also sometimes see it written like this: `MakeBoxes[g_?GraphQ, form_] := MakeBoxes[#, form]&@PrepForDisplay[g];`